# php to use mysqli producing json array

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I am learning php/mysql for a website I am building.  I had everything working but it was incredibly vulnerable and insecure with little error trapping.  I have begun trying to secure my code and the first thing I am trying to do is better handle errors and implement prepared statements to avoid sql injection.

Unfortunately I have got stuck at my first hurdle, I originally created my json array like this:

```
$myArray=array();
$tempArray = array();

while ( $row = $results->fetch_assoc())
{   
    $tempArray[0] = $row['unix_timestamp(end_date)'];
    $tempArray[0] *= 1000;
    $tempArray[1] = $row['bid'];
    array_push($myArray, $tempArray);
}
echo json_encode ($myArray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

That worked greate producing a json I could then use with highcharts on my website.

My question is this, I have updated my code to include prepared statements utilising `Prepare` and `bind_param` which works (tested by simply echoing the result) however I am really struggling to get the errors into an array as above:

```
 while ( $row = $select_stmt->fetch())
{   
    printf("%s %s\n", $col1, $col2);
    //$tempArray[0] = $col2;
    //$tempArray[0] *= 1000;
    //$tempArray[1] = $col1;
   //array_push($myArray, $tempArray); 
}
//echo json_encode ($tempArray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

The above prints the text out but whenever I try and use fetch_assoc are another alternative (i've done a lot of googling) I cannot get it to work.  I always receive the same sorts of errors "Call to undefined method..." How do I replicate what I had working and use mysqli with bind_result to produce an array?

I would appreciate understanding exactly where I am going wrong as I believe I am missing a concept which is leading me down the wrong paths when looking for a solution.

EDIT - I have checked and I am using the mysqlnd driver

UPDATED Code - I think this is closer - utilising the get_result method instead of "bind_result" before calling fetch_assoc again.

```
$result = $select_stmt->get_result();
$myArray=array();
$tempArray = array();

 while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $tempArray[0] = $row['end_date'];
    $tempArray[0] *= 1000;
    $tempArray[1] = $row['bid'];
    array_push($myArray, $tempArray);
}
echo json_encode ($tempArray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Unfortunately it only retrieves the first value and not the subsequent 10's or 100's or 1000's of rows

**SOLUTION** - correct array in the json_encode and use of the get_result function

```
$result = $select_stmt->get_result();

$myArray=array();
$tempArray = array();

while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    foreach ($row as $r){
        $tempArray[0] = $row['end_date'];
        $tempArray[0] *= 1000;
        $tempArray[1] = $row['bid'];
        array_push($myArray, $tempArray);
    }
}
echo json_encode ($myArray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: thanks for the down vote with no explanation - I have read a bunch of answers on here without understanding why the answer is given and/or not finding one exactly for my question.

Comment: Could you please show some more code that you received an error from?

Comment: I've updated the code with my most recent attempt - however it only returns one record.  I am not receiving an error anymore (I discovered I was calling functions in the wrong place).  It is simply how to try and display the results in an array now.  I am trying for loops now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the code, use $myArray instead of $tempArray

Comment: I have just posted my solution, the myArray was missing (woops I had edited it for testing earlier) but I have also included the get_result and foreach loop - is this a robust solution?  It does what I want it to...Add that detail to your answer (if its ok) and i'll accept it

Comment: It's tough to say without seeing how your sql statements are prepared, but in general prepared statements are far safer than a direct query string.

Comment: I'll just assume they are (they use prepare and bind_param) as I don't want to spam the question with just a review of what I have ...I know people don't like that.  Rather just deal with one thing, now to get my second query working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I hear ya. If you're looking for a code review, you can check out stack exchange's code review site. Your question might be better suited there.